# Get Moq to call a base class method that has not been overriden

Tags: .net, unit-testing, tdd, moq

I am using Asp.Net Identity in my MVC application and I have a class named `ApplicationSignInManager` that looks like this:

```
public class ApplicationSignInManager : SignInManager<ApplicationUser, string>
{
    public ApplicationSignInManager(ApplicationUserManager userManager, 
        IAuthenticationManager authenticationManager)
        : base(userManager, authenticationManager)
    {
    }

    public override Task<ClaimsIdentity> CreateUserIdentityAsync(ApplicationUser user)
    {
        return user.GenerateUserIdentityAsync((ApplicationUserManager)UserManager);
    }

    public static ApplicationSignInManager Create(IdentityFactoryOptions<ApplicationSignInManager> options, 
        IOwinContext context)
    {
        return new ApplicationSignInManager(context.GetUserManager<ApplicationUserManager>(), 
            context.Authentication);
    }
}
```

Now, I would like to write a unit test for an action on a controller. I am using the Microsoft Visual Studio Unit Test framework with Moq 4.5.10.

The action calls the `PasswordSignInAsync` method that is declared `virtual` in the base class `SignInManager<ApplicationUser, string>` but it is not overriden in the child class `ApplicationSignInManager`.

I have tried this option, too:

```
var mockSignInManager = new Mock<ApplicationSignInManager>()
        { CallBase = true };

mockSignInManager.Setup(
      m => m.PasswordSignInAsync(string.Empty, string.Empty, true, true));
```

But `PasswordSignInAsync` does not show up in the Intellisense and the compiler complains it cannot find that method on `ApplicationSignInManager`.

How do I get it to show up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I installed the NuGet package **Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Owin** in the unit test project and it started getting all the methods in the base class because that base class was in the **Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Owin.dll** assembly.

In short, if you want to access methods of a base class in your mock object, then if that base class is in an assembly separate from the derived class, you must add a reference to the base class assembly in your test project.